# General form of multiplication of a matrix by its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

When multiplying $A^T*A$, does it usually end up in the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\b&-2b\end{pmatrix}$? If not, are there any special cases where it does? If so, why?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a^2+b^2 & ac+bd \\ ac+bd & c^2+d^2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yours is a *very* special case, for example it applies only to $2\times 2$ matrices

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment, we generally have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a^2+b^2 & ac+bd \\ ac+bd & c^2+d^2\end{pmatrix} \overset{?} = \pmatrix{\alpha & -\frac 12 \beta\\ - \frac 12 \beta  & \beta} 
$$
Your question amounts to asking when $a,b,c,d$ are such that
$$
ac + bd = - \frac 12 (c^2 + d^2)
$$
Given any $c,d$, there is a line of solutions $(a,b)$ to this equation.